# django navbar not across the top, showing top left box instead

Tags: django, mobile, navbar

when viewing my django app in the laptop it is showing the menu as expected acress the width of the screen but when trying to run that menu in the mobile it is shown as a small box on the top left of the screen. How to fix that?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
      </li>
    </ul>
  <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

so whay is that happening? how to fix that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned `bootstrap` version.

> so whay is that happening?

Inside `<nav>` you are using `.collapse` and `navbar-expand-lg` class means when the browser width falls below 992 px the navbar will change to collapsed mode. That is why it is collapsed in your mobile.

> how to fix that?

If you want mobile menu at all width's just use `navbar-expand` class in place of `navbar-expand-lg`
Just use `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">`

Otherwise you have to override default `css` in your `main.css`

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: block!important;
}

.navbar-nav>li, .navbar-nav {
  float: left !important;
}
```

Comment: still same issue. this what i have in head section:

<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'cart/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'cart/css/templatemo-video-catalog.css' %}">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'cart/css/main.css' %}">

Comment: i also took off collapse still nothing

Comment: put @media (min-width: 576px) {
   .collapse {
       display: none !important;
   }
} in your main.css and add .collapse in div and check

Comment: i put the line of code in the head?

Comment: sorry my bad just rename navbar-expand-lg to navbar-expand. see my updated answer. All other remains same as before.

Comment: i did that stll same. do i still need to add the @media? where to add it

Comment: I think this should work. I have tried here and everything works as expected. Which bootstrap version are you using

Comment: are you reffering to this
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"

Comment: After referring this link also works as expected i remove -lg from <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark"> and it still works

Comment: can you share with me your code so i can compare what is wrong or if i have css overidding?

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wsu79jqa/

Comment: Have you compare ? If not are there jQuery popper and bootstrap cdn in your head if not add these files or cdn links then try again

Comment: i added them and still no luck.

Comment: override the css put it in your main.css or in last section of your head add this style and check if it works. Updated my answer

Comment: still not working...is there a way you can take a look at my main.html